# Redirect not working within a Laravel method

Tags: laravel

I want to redirect some of my urls as follows:

```
/myprefix/fashion => /fashion
```

So I added a method to the controller:

```
protected function myMethod($mySlug)
{
    if (preg_match('/myprefix\/(\w+)/', $mySlug, $myMatches)) {
        dump(myUrlHelper($matches[1])); // Outputs URL properly.
        redirect(myUrlHelper($matches[1]), 301); // ...but doesn't redirect.
        // I also tried:
        // return redirect(url($matches[1]), 301);
    }

    return false;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, are you only wanting to redirect `/myprefix/fashion` or would you be wanting to redirect `/myprefix/fashion/(.*)` as well?

Answer (score 1):

try adding return before redirect function, and remove dump function

```
protected function myMethod($mySlug)
{
    if (preg_match('/myprefix\/(\w+)/', $mySlug, $myMatches)) {
        return redirect(myUrlHelper($matches[1]), 301);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am understanding your codes

web.php

```
Route::get('/myprefix/{slug}', 'YourController@myMethod');
```

function

```
public function myMethod($mySlug)
{
    return redirect(myUrlHelper($mySlug), 301);
}
```